# Can I get the architecture of my website (Joomla 1.5.23)

Tags: module, joomla-1.5, software-architecture

I got hired for a job where I should enhance a website which where created on Joomla 1.5.23 before I got there.
Of course, anybody there can help me.

I am not a web expert. I was here for marketing development but get basic knowledge of HTML.

The website is a hard to understand one. The homepage contains modules and I would like to see the whole architecture of the website before doing things.

Could someone advise me on a good module or extension displaying the whole site like a diagram?

Thanks so much.

Comment: By the way, hello everybody.I was so in rush I forgot the basics.

Comment: Thanks Lodder.
The thing bugging me here is that even text are in a module.There is no homepage but a page displaying all the modules (youtube, diaporama, text). For the changing text as news, or videos I understand but the point is for some stuff as the intrduction I was surprised. I got to understand the structure so I wanted an overview of the website with all the calling modules of each page and each menu.
Please let me know if you get that. Sorry, as said I am not an expert and definetly not on Joomla. I worked before with a YGWYS software creating the frames, the tables,... Thanks.

Comment: I've deleted my answer and will just recommend you start reading the Joomla documentation to get an idea of how Joomla works cause I don't particularly want to write half the documentation below

Comment: Thanks Neil Robertson! I now can find the modules I need to change. The thing is that I don't have all the rights on the server. I wanted to upgrade to 2.5 or 3.5. i even checked the version of PHP required but here I don't have any rights on the server (I am a false admin as I cannot do much).

Answer (score 5):

Switching on the template preview mode might help so you can at least see the module positions.

This will help you figure where to go (i.e. which module in module manager) to edit particular text.

You can enable template preview mode by appending `/index.php?tp=1` to your domain name.

Joomla 1.5 is quite old now. In newer versions of Joomla (especially the imminent version 3.4), much can be edited via the front-end where Joomla novices and experts alike need not be concerned about whether the text is an article, module or something else. All you need to know is how to click the edit button that appears once you are logged in with suitable authority.